# jqueryui combobox: how do I get the value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I borrowed the code from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox but don't know how to get the value of the selected item.

Hoping for a simple straight answer rather than reading their docs for the next 2 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#combobox').val() might do the trick
```

ok, that's not correct. do it this way:

```
$( "#combobox" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

in there do a console.log($(ui).val()) or something like it

then you should be able to do either:
$('#combobox').text() or .val() to get its content.

Comment: no.. the #combobox is an HTML select element and the autocomplete/combobox does not 'select' one of the elements :( that would have been too simple.

Comment: no, I had tried the 'select' thing before with no luck.  my #combobox is a HTML select, so .text() just returns the entire list, not the item selected.  in fact none are selected by the process.  guess I'll have to read the manual.

Comment: ahh. I looked more into their code and added an ID to the text input they create so I could select that and get it's value.  all is right with the world again.

Answer (score 2):

in Easy UI combo box:
to get current value
$('#combobox').combobox('getValue')
to get current string
$('#combobox').combobox('getText')
hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using an 'input' element, this is how I got it to work.

```
<input type="text" id="comboBox" />
```

JavaScript

```
$("#comboBox option:selected").val()
```

That will return the value selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).combobox({ selected: function (event, obj) { 
  console.log(obj.item.value) // log val 
  window.location.href = obj.item.value; // if you are using a url then give this a go
} });
```

This might make things a bit simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$('#comboname').combobox('getValue')` to get the value.

for more information and demo, you can see here http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?

Answer (score 0):

first set id of textbox and then get value of that textbox and match it with text of option of dropdown, if option's text match then get its value.you can see example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bhargav3vedi/15nnru0d/) in jsfiddle

```
this.input = $("<input>")
     .appendTo(this.wrapper)
     .val(value)
     .attr('placeholder', "Enter Type...")
     .attr("title", "")

     // Set Id of Input Type Text    

     .attr('id', 'Mach')
     .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
     .autocomplete({
     delay: 0,
     minLength: 0,
     source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
     })
```